# Linux RPM subpackages installing different file content to same file location

Tags: linux, apache, rpm

I have a repository that builds an RPM to deploy an apache configuration setup. Up until now, I had two different repos for two different servers. Now I am adding three more server types to my build and don't want to keep creating repos for simple configuration changes. The configuration settings are similar, yet slightly different. Some use the same files, some use different, and some have the same files but with different content (like proxy configurations/certificate definitions/etc).

I started to look at using RPMs subpackage functionality. However, I am running into problems with files that are named the same but have slightly different content. Here is an example of my spec file:

```
Summary: Installs http conf files.
Name: web-conf
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
SOURCE0 : %{name}-%{version}-%{release}.tar.gz
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root
BuildArch: noarch

%description

%Summary

%package srv2
Summary: Installs srv2 http conf files.
SOURCE1 : %{name}-srv2-%{version}-%{release}.tar.gz
%description srv2

%Summary

%prep

%setup -q -c -n "srv1"
%setup -c -T -b 1 -n "srv2"

%build
# Empty section.

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}

mkdir -p %{buildroot}

# in builddir

/bin/cp -Ra * %{buildroot}

%clean

/bin/rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files

%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/rewrite.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

%files srv2

%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/apiproxy.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/rewrite.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
%config %attr(0440,apache,apache) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

This does build both of the RPMs: web-conf-1.0-1.noarch.rpm and web-conf-srv2-1.0-1.noarch.rpm. However, the problem is that the files that are in the same location are the same files (when they are supposed to be different). The prep section shows the two different sources being un-tarred into the srv1 and srv2 directories. But when the install section outputs from the rpmbuild process, it only shows doing a cd into the srv2 directory before it processes the two different `%files` sections.

Is there a way for force the `%install` section to use different directories before processing the `%files` section? What am I doing wrong? Are subpackages not the way to go here?

Comment: In general, RPM is not meant to be used as packaging for machine-specific configuration. Use Ansible for managing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

No. It cannot be done. All files in %files section are taken from the same buildroot. Therefore two files with the same path have to have the same content.